# How do I improve the efficiency of my WordPress GraphQL server for a static website

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, graphql, gatsby

I [recently built](https://github.com/jsindos/acfql) a graphql schema generation tool that inspects a JSON representation of a set of WordPress advanced custom fields to generate a graphql schema. The JSON representation is based on the custom post types and advanced custom fields present in the SQL database.

For example, defining a custom post type named `Office Location` with the custom fields `city` and `street_address` results in a graphql schema that can be queried in the following way:

```
officeLocations {
    post_title
    locationInformation {
        city
        streetAddress
    }
}
```

This results in underlying SQL queries of the form

```
SELECT
`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`
FROM `wp_postmeta` AS `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = 'street_address'
AND `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` = 176
LIMIT 1;
```

and

```
SELECT
`id`, `post_author`, `post_title`, `post_content`,
`post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `post_type`, `post_name`,
`post_date`, `post_parent`, `menu_order`, `guid`
FROM `wp_posts` AS `wp_posts`
WHERE (`wp_posts`.`id` = 176 OR `wp_posts`.`post_name` = NULL)
AND `wp_posts`.`post_status` = 'publish'
LIMIT 1;
```

that extract the advanced custom post information out of the `wp_postmeta` table by first traversing the `wp_posts` table.

Using this schema generation tool on the landing page of a modest website results in 4035 separate SQL queries to the database. I'm not sure if this is out of the ordinary, but it results in a slow execution time (~4s on my 2015 MacBook Pro).

I am looking to improve the efficiency of these graphql queries for a website whose data is rarely changing (essentially a static website). From research my four main avenues are

1. Batch queries using [Facebook's dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader). I have gleaned from [this source](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/700) and looking into the [batching capabilities of dataloader for SQL](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader/blob/master/examples/SQL.md) that it can be difficult to batch SQL queries generated by naive graphql resolvers.
2. Create less naive graphql resolvers using something like [join-monster](https://github.com/acarl005/join-monster)
3. Implement a key/value cache using Redis or Memcached that puts a [response-level cache in front of the GraphQL server](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/819#issuecomment-299043695)
4. Compile website with dynamic graphql requests into a purely static website, which is then deployed as a static website (removing graphql from the equation)

I am interested in the relative merits of these avenues as well as any others.

Comment: I mean, you metioned a lot of things here and I don't know what exactly the question is. Using techniques like dataloader should have a logarithmic effect on the amounts of queries sent. The problem you are facing seems to be originating in the fact that "autoatically generated" and "performance" are two things that take great effort to combine. In fact there are multiple companies that try to solve this problem like Prisma or [Hasura](https://github.com/hasura).

Comment: I suppose I don't have a clear cut question, however I am interested in the relative merits of different solutions to the problem. It seems dataloader is a 'harder' problem to engineer than simply caching results at the query level, however won't suffer the risk of explosion in cache usage. I think for my particular use case, as the data is essentially static and the queries are unchanging I will be caching at the query level. I'll report back my results after implementation.

Comment: Why not using 'wp-graphql' plugin ? 
Apollo client could be better in (normalized) query caching, batching etc.

Answer (score 2):

Before you embark on caching and other energy-intensive 'solutions', let's do some things to speed up the queries themselves.

**Query 1** (postmeta problem)

The standard `wp_postmeta` has an inefficient schema.  This is better:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta (
    post_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    meta_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    meta_value LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key),
    INDEX(meta_key)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) for explanation, what to do if you have 767 troubles, and how do deal with a requirement for `meta_id` (which is mostly useless).

Those tips will speed up most queries involving `wp_postmeta`.

**Query 2** (bad formulation)

- `wp_posts.post_name = NULL` always fails; instead say `wp_posts.post_name IS NULL`.
- Without an `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` will deliver an arbitrary row.
- `OR` does not optimize well...

Rewrite thus:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    ( ( SELECT ...
            FROM `wp_posts` AS `wp_posts`
            WHERE `wp_posts`.`id` = 176
              AND `wp_posts`.`post_status` = 'publish'
            LIMIT 1 )
      UNION DISTINCT
      ( SELECT ...
            FROM `wp_posts` AS `wp_posts`
            WHERE `wp_posts`.`post_name` IS NULL
              AND `wp_posts`.`post_status` = 'publish'
            LIMIT 1 )
    ) LIMIT 1
```

And then these would be beneficial:

```
INDEX(post_status, post_id)
INDEX(post_status, post_name)
```

If you add `ORDER BY`, it will need to be added in 3 places; just before each `LIMIT`.

Before:  A full table scan of `wp_posts`.  After my suggestions: two very efficient, single-row fetches, plus figuring which of the 2 rows do deliver.

Comment: Caching at the response-level does speed things up drastically but it's not a generalisable solution. I would like to engineer something at the DB or ORM level, so this is a great start. I am also dealing with inefficiencies involving double-table traversal to access WordPress categories as well as ORM processing to access ACF repeater fields as described [here](https://gist.github.com/jsindos/5289f105a3e34e8b04c3daaef62ac889).